# NullIf statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand how `nullif` is working. I have an error in this statement

```
 select 
    case 'Null if equal'
       when (MakeFlag = FinishedGoodsFlag) then null 
       else 1
    end
 from 
    Production.Product
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

So any help ? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `'Null if equal'` means in the `select case`

Comment: Where is the `NullIf` function?

Comment: It's not clear what you want, a result that either can be `null` or `1`(true) and never `0`(false)?

Comment: sample Code is no where near to the meaning of your question and description!!

Comment: Sorry I Confused between nullif and using case when I took the code copy and paste .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess  you want to use [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) which returns null if both are equal, or else the first expression:

```
SELECT [Null if equal] = NULLIF(MakeFlag, FinishedGoodsFlag)
FROM Production.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case 
when (MakeFlag = FinishedGoodsFlag) then null 
else 1
end as 'Null if equal'
from Production.Product
```

I think this would help you

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct, I think this should be:

```
 select case  when (MakeFlag = FinishedGoodsFlag) then null 
 else 1
 end as 'Null if equal'
 from Production.Product
```

Not sure where 'NullIf' comes into this.